# Where does Application name showup? Android / MonoAndroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am going through [this tutorial](http://android.xamarin.com/Documentation/Guides/Resource_Layouts)  and I am a bit confused of about this part

```
Inside the Resources/Values/ folder, open Strings.xml. This is where you should save all default text strings for your user interface. The default template for this file starts with two strings, hello and app_name. Revise hello to something else. Perhaps "Hello, Android! I am a string resource!" The entire file should now look like this:
view plainprint?

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <resources>  
        <string name="Hello">Hello, Android! I am a string resource!</string>  
        <string name="ApplicationName">Hello, Android</string>  
    </resources>
```

I would have thought it would show up as in the application menu(where you go to select the application you want)

However that does not seem to be the case. I am not sure if the code label is overriding it or what

```
[Activity(Label = "Test Test", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main); 
        }
    }
```

As I see "Test Test"

Comment: Hi, were you able to find the solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gets shown by the Package Installer when the user is Installing your app.

Answer (score 0):

label is the one that you in manage apps or in the app cabinet. the application name is optional.

**"An optional name of a class implementing the overall android.app.Application for this package"**

is what Eclipse says.